# Need to pull a logID and use it as a variable within storedProc

Tags: mysql

I need to be able to set the logID for a stored procedure. This works for selecting the correct log

```
SELECT l.logId
    FROM logs l WHERE l.details LIKE 'FCT%'
```

Now I need to take that logID and set it so that I can use it in a query such as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reportLogName ()

    BEGIN


     SET @lgID = logID  SELECT * FROM logs l WHERE l.details LIKE 'FCT%';
     SET @s = CONCAT(             
     'select * from logs where logid =',@tbl);

      PREPARE stmt FROM @s;

         EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        END //

    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the Log Id to the stored proecedure then us it in the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reportLogName (in mylogId int)
```

---

Edit after comment below. 
If you declare the varable then select it into the variable you will be able to use it later in the stored procedure.

```
 DECLARE mylogID Int;
 SET mylogID = (SELECT logID FROM logs l WHERE l.details LIKE 'FCT%');
```

Comment: I do not know the log name to pass in - that is why i need to check for the details - whichever log has the detail correct will be the log I need to use.

Comment: Ok so you want to find the logid in the stored procedure and then use it later in the stored procedure? Check edit.